# GCP create organization from command line or through API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-billing, cloud-security

Is there a way to create organizations programmatically in GCP using gcloud command or an API. I have several small orgs under which there are departments and then teams and finally products(projects). I wanted to have clean inheritance for security policies, standards, shared storage which could be defined at top level and applied across projects and also I wanted to have billing metrics at org level, so that it can be easily tracked where the spending is going..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Organization can be created only on console , although in the  [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/organizations) for `gcloud organizations` command description is:

> create and manage Google Cloud Platform Organizations

but there is no command for create.

Looking at your example I don't think that maintaining of several organization is good idea, as in another [doc](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-organization) I found that:

> The Organization resource is the **root node**

Which, I understand, is meant to be only one.

However, I suggest to use concept of "folder" which is described [here](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-folders). This concept is designed to create organization structure, and there is both API and  for [creation of folders](http://gcloud%20command) .

Comment: thanks for the details. if I use folder structure, Can I determine which part of the org is billed more for different resources? Is it possible to apply security policies across this folder structure?

Comment: When it comes security polices are managed by the same `gcloud organizations` command and I think should be possible to be managed well enough.  Please review the docs I have provided, you should find everything there. For the rest - I am not sure what do you mean by "billed more for different resources"....